# Java PreparedStatement equivalent for OraclePreparedStatement registerReturnParameter

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

OraclePreparedStatement has a registerReturnParameter that works with a "Returning into" sql clause.  What's the Java equivalent (and a SQL statement) that would do the same?  I believe getGeneratedKeys() only returns an auto-incremented column -- is there a way to get the entire resultset for all rows updated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried specifying the columns names or indizes to return in the `prepareStatement` call? Apart from the method that takes an in `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as parameter there are also versions allowing you to specify which columns to return.

Comment: Which ones were with Java PreparedStatement?

Comment: Is this a normal SQL statement or is this a stored procedure call?